# Google social login Can I use cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-signin

Can I check the login using cookies?

Only users logged in from php can view the page. With javascript the page loads and proceeds with redirection.

Use Xampp

```html
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-width="300px" data-longtitle="true"></div>
<script>
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
      var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
      var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
      setCookie('google_token', id_token,1);
    }

    var setCookie = function(name, value, exp) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + exp*24*60*60*1000);
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + ';expires=' + date.toUTCString() + ';path=/';
    };
</script>
```